# How can I evaluate a variable created inside a rule? (with eval)

Tags: makefile

I'm new to makefiles, and I'm stuck in this problem: how to create symbolic links to all the files in a directory found, all this inside a rule:

I want to know if a call to "find" retrieves any result. If I assign the result to a variable with "eval" (what is the only way I know to set a variable inside a rule), "ifdef" evaluation doesn't work.

I have also tried comparing to "" with "ifneq" But doesn't work.

Probably I'm following a wrong direction, so if someone has an alternative approach, I'll be very thankful.

Here the whole Makefile: (interesting line marked with ######)

Thank you a lot!

```
DEFAULT_YCS_ROOT := /opt/yujin

all:
ifdef YCS_ROOT
    @echo Looking for Yujin maps in ${YCS_ROOT}
else
    $(eval YCS_ROOT := ${DEFAULT_YCS_ROOT})
    @echo WARNING: YCS_ROOT is undefined. Looking for Yujin maps in default path ${YCS_ROOT}
endif

    $(eval MAPS_DIR := $(shell find ${YCS_ROOT} -name yujin_maps))
    @echo ${MAPS_DIR}  "${MAPS_DIR}"
ifdef MAPS_DIR  ######
###### misguided alternative....  ifneq (${MAPS_DIR}, " ")
    $(eval DEST_DIR := $(shell pwd)/resources/yaml/stage/maps)
    @echo Creating symbolic links on ${DEST_DIR} for every PGM map on ${MAPS_DIR}/maps
    rm ${DEST_DIR}/*.pgm
    for f in ${MAPS_DIR}/maps/*.pgm; do ln -s $$f ${DEST_DIR}/; done
else
    @echo ERROR: Yujin maps package not found in ${YCS_ROOT}. Define YCS_ROOT variable properly
endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, assuming you are using GNUMake, there is an easier way to handle `YCS_ROOT` and `DEFAULT_YCS_ROOT`:

```
DEFAULT_YCS_ROOT := /opt/yujin
YCS_ROOT ?= DEFAULT_YCS_ROOT
```

This will assign the value of `DEFAULT_YCS_ROOT` to `YCS_ROOT` if and only if `YCS_ROOT` is undefined.

For the variables `MAPS_DIR` and `DEST_DIR`, you are mixing Make syntax with shell syntax. I think the easiest approach is to define both variables outside the rule:

```
MAPS_DIR := $(shell find ${YCS_ROOT} -name yujin_maps)
DEST_DIR := $(shell pwd)/resources/yaml/stage/maps
```

You should test all of this to make certain that the variables have the values you expect. **It seems that you expect only one directory in `MAPS_DIR`; I will follow that convention, but it is unsafe.** Once the makefile so far is working, you can add the rule. You can use a shell loop:

```
all:
    rm ${DEST_DIR}/*.pgm
    for f in ${MAPS_DIR}/maps/*.pgm; do echo ln -s $$f ${DEST_DIR}/; done
```

or use Make syntax (which gives some advantages):

```
MAPS := $(wildcard $(MAPS_DIR)/maps/*.pgm)
DEST_MAPS := $(patsubst $(MAPS_DIR)/maps/%.pgm, ${DEST_DIR}/%.pgm, $(MAPS))

all: $(DEST_MAPS)

${DEST_DIR}/%.pgm: $(MAPS_DIR)/maps/%.pgm
    rm $@
    ln -s $< ${DEST_DIR}/
```

Comment: Impressive lesson of Makefile writting. Thanks a lot, works fine. Yeah, for sure I must add a check for find's result; I wanted to have something just running, and improve as soon as I find time.

Comment: +1 for going beyond just answering the question, and educating us in writing makefiles -- thanks.